# WooCommerce | Set billing field value

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to pre-populate the values for the checkout's billing fields to the DB stored values of the user **before his first purchase**.

I've tried the following code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , function ( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing']['billing_first_name']['placeholder'] = 'First Name';
    $fields['billing']['billing_first_name']['default'] = wp_get_current_user()->user_firstname;
    return $fields;
});
```

I've read about this solution in an [other post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/219604/woocommerce-how-to-populate-custom-select-field-with-stored-values-on-checkout). Placeholder works great, but the value doesn't.

Also, the [WooCommerce Doc](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/) (Lesson 1) doesn't say about anything the array value 'default'

Comment: Can you show more of the code you are using?

Comment: @helgatheviking I've just updated the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're pretty close. This worked for me. I don't know if it was necessary, but I used a named function and only get the `user_firstname` property if the user exists.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'kia_checkout_field_defaults', 20 );
function kia_checkout_field_defaults( $fields ) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $first_name = $user ? $user->user_firstname : '';
    $fields['billing']['billing_first_name']['placeholder'] = 'First Name';
    $fields['billing']['billing_first_name']['default'] = $first_name;
    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Helga, I've added priority 20 to my code and it worked!