# Set value of woocommerce woocommerce_form_field

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to prefill the value of woocommerce_form_field with a variable. The idea is that I would suggest this value to the customer and if they liked it they would leave it, if not they can edit it. I can easily change the placeholder, but that is not passed to order when it processed. How do I change the actual value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Woocommerce: Set checkout field values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45602936/woocommerce-set-checkout-field-values)

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. You just set the default value in the same section where label and placeholder are declared like:
'default' => $fullname,